# How to check i18n message resource arguments is empty or not?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, internationalization

I mean for example this is my messages.properties file:

```
BFF.ERROR.PRODUCT_NOT_FOUND = Product with {0} not found
```

I want to do that if the arguments array is empty, the client shouldn't see the message like this

> Product with {0} not found

I want to the user see this one

> Product not found.

Can I do something like that?

```
BFF.ERROR.PRODUCT_NOT_FOUND = Product with {0} not found | Product not found
```

Answer (score 0):

I think u can define two keys :

```
BFF.ERROR.PRODUCT_NOT_FOUND = Product with {0} not found 
BFF.NULL.PRODUCT_NOT_FOUND = Product not found
```

then deal with it in code

Answer (score 0):

Why would the arguments array be empty? Can you not use two different keys and check ahead of time to use the correct message based on the arguments? They're two different messages and should have their own keys.

messages.properties

```
key1=message with argument {0}
key2=message without argument
```

Somewhere in your code

```
final String msg;
if (condition) {
    msg = ... // if you have the argument for placeholder {0}, get message for key1
} else {
    msg = ... // fallback, get message for key2
}
```

If you *really* wanted to you could look into creating a custom message source and/or supporting beans and handle this kind of thing there but it seems like more trouble than it's worth. In that case, have a look at the [MessageSourceSupport](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/support/MessageSourceSupport.html) class Spring provides, in particular methods [formatMessage](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/support/MessageSourceSupport.html#formatMessage-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object:A-java.util.Locale-) and [renderDefaultMessage](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/support/MessageSourceSupport.html#renderDefaultMessage-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object:A-java.util.Locale-).